# How to get a custom value for a field type in sonata?

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

With Sonata, when I create a contract with a choiceType, the user can choose contract1 or contract2 and in my database I would get "451" for contract1 and "678" for contract2.
In my Field List all my data are displayed but for my contract I've got either "451" or "678" and I would like instead of those numbers, contract1 or contract2.
This is my field for creating the contract :

```php
$mapper
            ->add('contract', ChoiceType::class, [
                'choices' => [
                    'contract1' => '451',
                    'contract2' => '678',
                ],
            ])
```

And in my code for the field, I don't know how to tell it if 451 then 'contract1'. I started like that :

```php
->add('contract', null, [
                'label' => 'Contract',
            ])
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the form entity type which would solve your problem:

```
$builder->add('contract', EntityType::class, [
    // looks for choices from this entity
    'class' => Contract::class,
    // uses the Contrzct.name property as the visible option string
    'choice_label' => 'name',
    // Query builder to select your to specific contract
    'query_builder' => function (ContractRepositoty $contractRepository) {
        return $contractRepository->createQueryBuilder('support_time_slot')
            ->where('contract.id  in :ids')
            ->setParameter('ids', [461,678])
            ->orderBy('contract.name');
        },
    // used to render a select box, check boxes or radios
    'multiple' => true,
    'expanded' => true,
]);
```

Comment: Thanks, 'choice_label' => 'name', is solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I created a specific template and in it I translated the value I wanted:

```php
->add('contract', null, [
     'label' => 'Contract',
     'template' => 'AdminBundle:ContractAdmin:list__operation.html.twig'
    ])
```

And my Twig :

```
{% extends 'SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_list_field.html.twig' %}

{% block field %}
    {% if value %}
        {{ ('contract.operation.'~value~'.value')|trans }}
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```